# javascript: how to trim excessive backslashes in JSON?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have crazy amount of backslashes in some of my JSON strings.

example:

```
{"xpath":"//*[@id=\\\\\\\\"pagination_contents\\\\\\\\\\\\"]/div[3]/div/div/form/div[2]/a","title":"keyword"}
```

I would like to shave anything more than `\"` so `\\\\\\\\"` would be `\"`. Any amount of `\\\\` would be trimmed.

I tried

str.replace("\\\"","\"") and not sure how to account for varying amount of backslashes.

Comment: Just FYI: to remove a single ``\`` globally, you need to use something like `.replace(/\\/g, '')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.replace(/\\\\+/g, "\\")` should do the trick

for example `"abc\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\def\\\\\\\ghi".replace(/\\\\+/g, "\\")` will return `"abc\def\ghi"`